# how to implement a custom template for a custom form fields for data entry for an assets/inventory management system

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm in the process of developing an web based inventory system. i'm currently at the design and i've gotten stumped.

The problem is, by my design all assets will have some basic fields that they all share for example

- Reg Code
- Type
- Description
- RFID code
- Serial

But some assets however need to have custom fields based on the type of assets, a car for example will have fields such as:

- Chasis No
- Vehicle Class

And these fields are not part of the basic fields presented to a user by default for addition of assets, and i'm trying to avoid hard coding the custom fields for different assets because they might be need for the user to add a different kind of asset that i didn't plan for in the future hereby requiring my attention and extra coding for the custom fields of the new assets being added.

So here is my question, how to do i implement the system such that when a User is creating an "Asset Type"(Not the asset itself e.g "car", "computer",) he can specify a template for the custom fields that will be available to users when they want to add an asset of the "asset type" ? Additionally i'll like to know what the database will look like because i plan to create a table to contain all assets and the other custom field will be in another table (although this idea is open to changes if a reason is given).

PS: I just need a brief idea of the design, i dont mind reading it up myself if u point me in the right direction. And i'm developing the system in Java with Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, why not create a base "Asset" class and then extend it for the more specific examples, then have a table that relates a given type of asset to a specific JSP?

Or, even better, if you make your "Asset" be more generic, using a properties map instead of using inheritance to separate the Asset types, and have a field to determine the template to use.  You could even write a custom [ViewResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html) to read the templates out of a table.  Or get REAL fancy and make your `ViewResolver` build the view directly off the Asset.

There are lots of ways to go with this.  You can get hyper-dynamic, and make things crazy and integrated and all that jazz, or you can get brute-force-ish and use the more direct method.  I think it depends on your requirements and how much time, money, effort you want to spend.